# driver.find_element fails when there is a blank bar in the bar chart

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, svg, xpath

I have the below graph to automate and extract the information that is displayed in the tooltip on hover action. [image]

The SVG XPath for the area that covers the bars is:

```
//div[contains(@class,'commonGraphStyle__CommonGraphStyle')][3]//*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='dxc-series']//*[name()='rect']
```

Since the `driver.find_elements` on the above XPath returns a list of elements, I have collected them in a list (bars). There is some information that is displayed on hovering on each bar in the chart (as can be seen in the screenshot). I iterate thru the list (bars), get the locator of the tooltip, and extract the text from that using:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='dxc-tooltip']/div/div").text)
```

However when the control comes to the bar on 28-May, where the bar is actually not present, I get a `NoSuchElementException`, and the for loop immediately exits without going to the next set of bars.

Another problem is the tooltip is only displayed when we hover either on the bars, or on the points above the graph on the pink line. However, when I try to get the text using:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='dxc-tooltip']/div/div").text)
```

by hovering on the circles on the pink line, it fails right at the first iteration with the same error.

Can someone help me how do I handle this.

Comment: _I get a NoSuchElementException_ So put that code in a try/except block and catch the exception.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Can you please provide DOM structure so we could help you?

Comment: @Yaroslavm
This is how the tooltip hierarchy is:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TfizgsH1CQu65VspjVC5tcZtY30oOVCL_eZHcPefX1E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And the one for the bars:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SOuCGPgUBGSmtMIwqLefWic2ThwxDcpnUwml19fPdtw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnGordon The problem with doing it in try/except is that it will entirely skip the info on such dates, info which I also actually need for my validations.

Comment: Sounds like you had too much code inside the try/except block.

Answer (score 0):

By provided html structure, selector for your graphic nodes that are not empty is

`.dxc-markers > rect:not([height='0'])`

So, you can search for elements collection

`nodes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dxc-markers > rect:not([height='0'])']`

loop into them and hover each element

```js
for node in nodes:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(node).perform()
    text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class*=graphTooltipStyle]")
    print(text)
```

If tooltip is not appeared directly after hover, you can wait for it, using `WebDriverWait` inside loop.